# Mutually Exclusive Binary Variables

Tags: r, binary-data

I am currently constructing predictive models using bayesglm, naive bayes and bayesian network modelling. My data set consists of mutually exclusive binary variables where 1 indicates presence and zero indicates absence. Where one variable is present, it means that other variables are absent because they are mutually exclusive. For example, I am using political violence data and therefore when trying to predict an attack on police target, the model is as follows:

```
bayesglm(PoliceTarget ~ ProvinceA, ProvinceB, ProvinceC, BombAttack, ArmedAssault, Assassination, GroupA, GroupB, GroupC)
```

I would like to know whether it is problematic to use variables in this format in the models? Should I instead group such binary variables into Province, AttackType and Group, so that they all contain the appropriate levels. The model would then read:

```
bayesglm(PoliceTarget ~ Province, Attacktype, Group)
```

Which model construction format should I employ?

Comment: The [formula](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) is wrong, it should be `PoliceTarget ~ Province + Attacktype + Group`. See also section `11.1  Defining statistical models; formulae` of R-intro.pdf that comes with your installation of R.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Can I use mutually exclusive binary variables in such a model or is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you can. As long as the response is binary the regressors can be binary, factor with several levels or continuous.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just to double check: I can use mutually exclusive binary variables as regressors in this model? As opposed to non-mutually exclusive binary variables. Where the presence (indicated by 1 rather than zero) of a particular binary variable mutually excludes the presence of another binary variable, (for example the same political violence attack can't happen at the same time in two different provinces), does inclusion of such variables cause the predictive outputs from the model to become suspect? Thanks